# Load test a .NET desktop client

Tags: .net, client-server, load-testing

I need to automate load tests on a .NET desktop application using an automated script, preferably one that is able to record mouse clicks and keyboard entries.

I will have about 10 desktops at my disposal and I want to simulate up to 10 users on each box (as an alternative to installing 100 boxes).

Are there any tools that can be used to perform this? This application does NOT have an HTTP interface so a regular web based load testing tool can not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [QuickTestPro](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24%5E1352_4000_100__). We use it for Web and Windows applications.

That said, if these applications are calling a database back-end, you might consider just [stress testing the database](http://www.sqledit.com/stress/) itself. I think you are going to have a hard time getting the volume (100 concurrent users) you are looking for with any kind of tool. That is, how will it have 10 instances of your application open at one time?

Good luck!

Comment: Matt's right.  It sounds like your trying to test the database or middle tier's.  In that case just stress the back end directly.

Answer (score 0):

Mercury (now owned by HP I believe) has made a long-time business of delivering scale-out test tools.

If you want to try to automate some of it yourself, check out the [UI Automation Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) which Microsoft is now shipping.